# Error 500 access in rails app with puma and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, puma

I have 6 containers to create my own application with microservices. In this [project](https://github.com/kalelc/docker-to-rails-with-rbenv) I have an example app. The problem happens when I try to access to the URL (`http://localhost:80/`) the browser returns error 500 with message:

> return We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the
>   application owner check the logs for more information.

List Containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                      NAMES
69ee0ef25faa        falcon_nginx        "/usr/sbin/nginx"        59 seconds ago       Up 10 seconds                   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp         falcon_nginx_1
411e41943a35        falcon_web          "foreman start"          About a minute ago   Up 11 seconds                   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp     falcon_web_1
95de66fe7aae        redis               "/entrypoint.sh redis"   About a minute ago   Up 12 seconds                   6379/tcp                   falcon_redis_1
7693b7e2d2eb        memcached:latest    "/entrypoint.sh memca"   About a minute ago   Up 12 seconds                   0.0.0.0:11211->11211/tcp   falcon_memcached_1
020566c4a77a        mysql:latest        "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About a minute ago   Up 12 seconds                   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp     falcon_db_1
7bf8176503f4        busybox             "true"                   About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                              mysql_data
```

Log:

```
web_1       | 14:34:04 web.1  | started with pid 32
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | started with pid 33
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | ==> log/puma.stderr.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | === puma startup: 2015-11-05 10:39:01 -0300 ===
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | === puma startup: 2015-11-09 14:33:16 +0000 ===
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | 
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | ==> log/development.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | 
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | ==> log/puma.stdout.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [17288] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [17288] === puma shutdown: 2015-11-05 10:39:07 -0300 ===
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [17288] - Goodbye!
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | === puma startup: 2015-11-09 14:33:16 +0000 ===
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [31] * Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1447079596225-31
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [31] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [39] Early termination of worker
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [43] Early termination of worker
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [31] === puma shutdown: 2015-11-09 14:33:24 +0000 ===
web_1       | 14:34:04 log.1  | [31] - Goodbye!
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] Puma starting in cluster mode...
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] * Version 2.11.2 (ruby 2.1.5-p273), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 16
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] * Environment: development
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] * Process workers: 2
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] * Phased restart available
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] * Listening on unix:///home/app/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
web_1       | 14:34:05 web.1  | [32] Use Ctrl-C to stop
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | === puma startup: 2015-11-09 14:34:05 +0000 ===
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | 
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | ==> log/puma.stderr.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | === puma startup: 2015-11-09 14:34:05 +0000 ===
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | 
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | ==> log/puma.stdout.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | [32] * Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1447079645129-32
web_1       | 14:34:09 log.1  | [32] - Worker 1 (pid: 44) booted, phase: 0
web_1       | 14:34:09 log.1  | [32] - Worker 0 (pid: 40) booted, phase: 0
```

Nginx site:

```
upstream rails {
  server web fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 2M;
  server_name localhost;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  root /home/app/public;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    gzip_static on;
    expires     max;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    error_page 404              /404.html;
    error_page 422              /422.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /500.html;
    error_page 403              /403.html;
  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    expires    max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

For more details check [project](https://github.com/kalelc/docker-to-rails-with-rbenv)

```
Docker version 1.8.1
docker-compose version: 1.4.0
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What's in the nginx log?

Comment: @japed nginx does not return any errors

Comment: What about these `log/puma.stderr.log` and `log/puma.stdout.log`  They're listed in your log above, I assume they're logging something there?

Comment: @japed yes, Check **Log** in my question.

Comment: Which log is the one in your question?

Comment: `web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | ==> log/puma.stderr.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | === puma startup: 2015-11-09 14:34:05 
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | ==> log/puma.stdout.log <==
web_1       | 14:34:05 log.1  | [32] * Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1447079645129-32
web_1       | 14:34:09 log.1  | [32] - Worker 1 (pid: 44) booted, phase: 0
web_1       | 14:34:09 log.1  | [32] - Worker 0 (pid: 40) booted, phase: 0`

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your nginx conf:

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
```

Try this:

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @rails;
```

Comment: yes, perfect. Had seen it, I had forgotten to correct it. also thanks!!.

Comment: 50/50, look at my solution with your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found the problem with help @ehoffmann

1. As comments @ehoffmann i have change `app` to `rails`.
2. Communication between puma and nginx must be via tcp. I change in `docker-compose.yml` line `command: foreman start` to `command: bundle exec puma -e development -p 3000`

Log: `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000`

Comment: Ok if you want to keep socket communication, you could keep `foreman start` and replace `server web fail_timeout=0;` with `server unix:///home/app/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;` in nginx.conf upstream section.

Comment: @ehoffmann but remember that nginx is a one container and puma other container, communication between containers is tcp.

Comment: yes but you have a `volume_from: web` in your docker-compose.yml. With this config, you could access the `/home/app/tmp/sockets/puma.sock` directly from your nginx container.